# Database disappear from Failover Group

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, failover

I run an Azure subscription with a main SQL Server in West Europe and a georeplicated SQL Server in North Europe with a failover group. In these servers I have two elastic pools with the same name.

Everything has been working fine since yesterday.
From yesterday when I create a new database on West Europe and add it to the failover some old databases are removed from the failover.
I tried deleting and recreating with a new name the failover group and the secondary server, but the situation became even more strange: I started adding a couple of databases to the failover group and when I connect to the failover group using SQL Management Studio I see all my databases in the failover (even the one I haven't added since failover recreation). Opening one of these databases that shouldn't be there, no tables were showing.
Ignoring this problem I added more databases to the failover group and some old databases disappear from the failover again.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How many databases were in the failover group/pool?

Comment: We have 230 dbs in failover group.

Comment: When you do these activities are you using the portal or powershell?

Comment: I used the portal.

Comment: I tried again today and everything works fine.... I suspect some kind of Azure bug.